# Variable in wrong scope (maybe needs a closure?)

Tags: javascript, closures, lexical-closures

I have the following code that is in need of a closure:

```
var numItems = document.getElementsByClassName('l').length;
for (var i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {
  document.getElementsByClassName('l')[i].onclick = function (e){
    preview(this.href, i);
  };
}
```

What happens is that whenever an item is clicked, preview always the same number for i

I suspect what I need to do is

```
function indexClosure(i) {
  return function(e) {
    preview(this.href, i);
  }
}
```

And assign the onclick's like this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('l')[i].onclick = indexClosure(i);
```

But then `this` would no longer refer to my link... how is this problem solved?

Comment: It does: http://jsfiddle.net/eKuh3/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use closure to capture the counter of the cycle:

```
var numItems = document.getElementsByClassName('l').length;
for (var i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {
  (function(i){
    document.getElementsByClassName('l')[i].onclick = function (e){
      preview(this.href, i);
    };
  }(i))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

doesn't onclick pass in `(sender, eventArgs)` allowing you to access `this` through `sender`?